# jQuery get the form select value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am working with a jQuery code. The code listen from an event "change" from the radio button. I want to use select instead. How can I make this work?. See  the code below

```
$("#filters input:radio").on("change", function () {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be

```
$("#filters select").on("change", function () {
```

As select is not an input tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#filters select").on("change", function () {
```

Comment: wouldn't it just be `$("#filters select")`?  what's `:select`? and - and input would grab inputs which don't have a `type=select ` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: did not work. I am getting an error

"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: select"

Comment: A select is not an input tag ! And there is no such thing as  `input:select ` !

Answer (score 2):

What is your HTML like ? Select and radios are two different tags, for example :

**Radio filter**

```
    0<input type="radio" name="filter1" value="0">
    1<input type="radio" name="filter1" value="1">
    2<input type="radio" name="filter1" value="2">
```

**Select filter**

```
    <select name="filter2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

Therefore, the jquery syntax is almost the same :

**Radio**

```
$('input[type=radio][name=filter1]').on('change', function() {
    //val changed to $(this).val();
});
```

**Select**

```
$('select[name=filter2]').on('change', function() {
    //val changed to $(this).val();
});
```

See a working **[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdekB/1/)**.